# Comparing swipe and single screen Android

Tags: java, android

I like to know a code to solved when the users just tap (single tap) and swipe screen.
My program will do different action beetwen single tap (Toast) and swipe screen (Intent).

I used it to detect swipe

```
private float x1, x2, x3;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x1 = event.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        x2 = event.getX();

        float deltaX = x2 - x1;
        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
            if (x2 < x1) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Music2.class);

                startActivityForResult(i, 500);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                        R.anim.slide_out_left);
                this.onDestroy();
            }

            // Right to left swipe action
            else if (x2 > x1) {
                // Intent i=new Intent
                // (getApplicationContext(),Music2.class);
                //
                // startActivity(i);
            }

        }
        break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I tried many way to make different beetwen single tap and swipe screen.
You're code, I'll be apreciate.

Comment: can you put your full code?

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

 @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        // Your logic here
    }
});
```

And add the following code in onTouch listener

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Still cant fix it, can you post your example application which representative? So sorry.